# remove the value set in input field's value attribute after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I am using HTML, bootstrap, php, MySQL, and Ajax. I want that when I submit the form the value set in the input field's value attribute become null. I am badly stuck here. Can anyone please advice me that how can I solve this problem?? Thanks in advance guys. codes are given below :

```
            <form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post">
            <label>Roll No : </label>
            <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" value="12"><br>
            <label>Name : </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Sneha"><br>
            <label>Stream : </label>
            <select name="stream" id="stream">
                <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                <option value="IT">IT</option>
                <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
                <option value="ME">ME</option>
            </select><br>
            <label>Age : </label>
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btn-submit').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"insert.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:$('#cForm').serialize(),
                    success:function(data)
                    {

                            document.getElementById("cForm").reset();
                            $("input[type='text']").val('');

                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: how are you submitting the form using page load on the same page or using ajax?

Comment: the traditional `form.reset()` wont work if you hardcode a value in the input you will have to reset all the inputs manually if you are looking for that , otherwise if you are trying to enter som text and want it to be reset once the form is submitted you can call the `document.querySlector("#form-id").reset()`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam how to remove the default values after submitting the form? Yes, I am using ajax.

Comment: you need to call `$("input[type='text']").val('');` inside the `ajax` success function, see answer below it just resets once you click submit

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Using  $("input[type='text']").val('');  doesn't help.

Comment: see the edit section of my answer and add your complete code, you are not helping by saying this does not work , add the code where you are using it inside your question

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam see the edited code above. But the default value of the input field still occurs after submitting the form.

Comment: what does the `ajax` call show you is it successful or not ? see the console for errors. add `console.log("hello world")` inside the success function just after the `$("input[type='text']").val('');` and see if it shows up in console

Comment: and you should add your code inside the `$("#cForm").on("submit", function(e) {` rather than on click, or use the `type="button"` instead of `submit` for the button you are binding the click function

Comment: please mark the answer as correct that helped you solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove default values of input fields, because on submit the page refreshes and default values will popup. Next you should create an event listener "submit". Once it is present find the nodes with input and replace the value with empty string. The working sample is bellow:

```
<form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post">
    <label>Roll No : </label>
    <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" value=""><br>
    <label>Name : </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><br>
    <label>Stream : </label>
    <select name="stream" id="stream">
        <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
        <option value="IT">IT</option>
        <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
        <option value="ME">ME</option>
    </select><br>
    <label>Age : </label>
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="submit" class="btn-modify" name="modify" value="Modify">

</form>

    <script>
        const form = document.querySelector('#cForm');
        let inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input')
        form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
            console.log('Submit');
            inputs.name.value = '';
            inputs.roll.value = '';
            inputs.age.value = '';
        })
    </script>
```

Don't forget to remove default value from input!!! Otherwise you will see them after submit.

Comment: You can also use reset() function on the form in the event listener function as suggested by @muhammad-omer-aslam

Comment: `form.reset()` wont work for the values hardcoded for the value attribute in the `input` tag, that is what i was talking about , not the user typed value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$("input[type='text']").val('');` to remove the values hardcoded in the input's `value` tag.

```js
$("#cForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("input[type='text']").val('');


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cForm" name="cForm" method="post">
  <label>Roll No : </label>
  <input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" value="112"><br>
  <label>Name : </label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="john"><br>
  <label>Stream : </label>
  <select name="stream" id="stream">
    <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
    <option value="IT">IT</option>
    <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
    <option value="ME">ME</option>
  </select><br>
  <label>Age : </label>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="submit" class="btn-modify" name="modify" value="Modify">

</form>
```

## `EDIT`

You are using `ajax` to submit the form so you should add the line `$("input[type='text']").val('');` inside you ajax success callback function

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/some-url/file.php',
  success:function(data){
       //your code to check if the save was success full 
      //and if yes then reset the form inputs
      $("input[type='text']").val(''); 
  }
});
```

Comment: what does **doesnt help** mean what exact error do you get how have you used it in your code? @SnehaRoy